# Google+ saving token not working

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-plus

My aim is to provide one time login to with google plus. I basically want to save the access token and then reuse it when the user returns. I have tried many forums and have tried various codes for the last 2 days. Its not working. Could anyone please help.

**First time login code:**

```
$client = new apiClient();
$client->setApplicationName("xxxx");
$client->setAccessType("offline");
$client->setClientId(GCLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret(GCLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setRedirectUri('xxxx');
$client->setDeveloperKey('xxxx');
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me'));
$url = $client->createAuthUrl();
//redirected to this url
```

**Code on return url**

```
$client = new apiClient();
$client->setApplicationName("xxxx");
$client->setClientId(GCLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret(GCLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setRedirectUri('xxxx');
$client->setDeveloperKey('xxxx');
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me'));
$client->setAccessType("offline");
$plus = new apiPlusService($client);

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $client->authenticate();
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    gp_reg($_SESSION['access_token']); 
   **//this function saves the access token to the database**
}
```

**When the user returns**

```
$client = new apiClient();
$client->setApplicationName("xxxx");
$client->setClientId(GCLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret(GCLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setRedirectUri('xxxxx');
$client->setDeveloperKey('xxxx');
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me'));
$client->setAccessType('online');
$client-> setApprovalPrompt("auto");
$plus = new apiPlusService($client);

print_r($row['token']);

$client->setAccessToken($row['token']);
// **$row['token'] contains the token from database**
```

**Error Message:**

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'apiAuthException' with message '**Could not json decode the access token**' in /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/src/auth/apiOAuth2.php:144
stack trace leads to the last line above "$client->setAccessToken($row['token'])"

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a similar problem, and may help you with the best way to handle the token that has been returned. It sounds like this may be an issue between how it is sent back as JSON and how it is stored (possibly as a string and not a JSON object).

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-api-php-client/fc7RUw1Pf44/TKpEihEp35wJ

If that is the case, you may need to reconstitute it as an object when you get it out of the database.

Or you may want to just make sure you're using the refresh_token value, since that is really what you need to use.